# Cannot compile CUDA program using nvcc remotely

Tags: nvidia, ssh, compiling, cuda

I am trying to access my Ubuntu machine remotely using putty from Windows. I have created a new user to access my Ubuntu machine. The new user can execute commands like gcc but cannot execute nvcc to compile CUDA codes. When nvcc is run on commandline the message comes as under: 
**"The program 'nvcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit"**

But if I login with user with root privilege it works. How can I allow users created by me to access nvcc for compiling and running CUDA programs?

Comment: You don't have NVCC installed or do you?

Comment: Change the permission of the script needed to run CUDA programs. I don't know about that but to change permissions use `chmod`. It should be something like `chmod 777 ~/path/to/nvcc`.

Comment: I have tried changing the mode. But I found that if I go to the location of nvcc (/usr/local/cuda/bin), I am able to run the command. But when I created the new user, I do not find the .bashrc file that can help set me this path. Shall I have to create a new .bashrc for the new user?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by creating a new .bashrc file in the new user home directory. Then I exported the CUDA paths as under:

export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-7.5
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64
PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH

After that the nvcc is able to run.

Comment: After every fresh login from putty, I have to source bashrc file again. Is their any alternative to avoid sourcing bashrc after each login?

Comment: Got the answer to my previous comment. I need to create (if not already present) a .bashrc_profile file in the user home directory and add a last line "source .bashrc". This will allow the nvcc to work at every login without sourcing. Very well explained in this link http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/13014